# I need an unique button name attribute generated by php or a database

Tags: php, html, sql, button, attributes

I'm doing a little project for my own to make my own episode list of my favourite shows and I have buttons for plus and min (episodes seen). But if I click one button both entries (from the database) do plus or min. Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `shows`");
$query->execute();
$table = "";
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $eps = $row['eps'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $seen = $row['seen'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $plus = "plus";
    $min = "min";
    $table .= "
<tr>
    <td>" . $id . "</td>
    <td>" . $name . "</td>
    <td>" . $eps. "</td>
    <td>" . $status . "</td>
    <td>" . $seen . "/" . $eps . "</td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='plus' value='+'></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='min' value='-'></td>
</tr>
";

    if (isset($_POST['plus'])) {
        $seen++;
        $fill = $db->prepare("UPDATE `shows` SET `seen` = '$seen' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        $fill->execute();
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['min'])) {
        $seen--;
        $order66 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `shows` SET `seen` = '$seen' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        $order66->execute();
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    $alert = "";
    if ($seen == $eps) {
        $alert = "Move " . $name . " to completed?<br>
        <input type='button' value='Yes'><input type='button' value='No'>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your logic is flawed here, is this the entire code?

Comment: there is no way, in the sql, to reference the actual ID associated with the particular row / records - the value stored in `$id` will be that of the last row - the button when click will therefore post the form ( assuming there is a form ) with the wrong ID.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `inputs` to `buttons`, like this

```
<td><button type='submit' name='plus' value='$id'>+</button></td>
<td><button type='submit' name='min' value='$id'>-</td>
```

This will allow you to use the `$id` as the value of each button.

Then you can change your queries just a bit to use the id value in the posted `plus` or `min`.

```
if (isset($_POST['plus'])) {
    $fill = $db->prepare("UPDATE `shows` SET `seen` = `seen` + 1 WHERE `id` = ?");
    $fill->execute(array($_POST['plus']));
} elseif (isset($_POST['min'])) {
    $fill = $db->prepare("UPDATE `shows` SET `seen` = `seen` - 1 WHERE `id` = ?");
    $fill->execute(array($_POST['min']));
}
```

Also (very importantly) move these update queries OUTSIDE the while loop. With the way you currently have it, having the update done inside the loop means that you are updating for every record in your table, which obviously isn't what you want. If you left the update queries inside the loop with the modifications I showed, they would just update the same row repeatedly, which is mostly harmless, but totally pointless.